# 3 columns grid displayed as 1 column on big screen 1920px

Tags: html, css

In [my site](https://chrisbg69.github.io/), I have a grid on the homepage section `.grid-container`. It looks fine on 1024px monitor, but on 1920px it's displayed in one column, how can I fix this?

```css
.grid-conteiner {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(350px, 1fr)); 
  grid-gap: 1em;
  margin-bottom: 2em;
}
```

Comment: Looks ok to me, I have a 27 inch monitor - 2650px and I see 2 columns. Just like the styles is `@media (min-width: 1700px) -> grid-template-columns: repeat (auto-fit, minmax (500px, 1fr));`

Comment: Ok,but i want 3 columns, what @mediaquery can i use for 3 columns, i have tv 49" 4k

Comment: Just delete this piece of code.
`@media (min-width: 1700px)
.grid-conteiner {
     display: grid;
     grid-template-columns: repeat (auto-fit, minmax (500px, 1fr));
     grid-gap: 1em;
     margin-bottom: 2em;
}`

Comment: I deleted code, how looks on your monitor now, on tv is 1 column again.

Comment: I already have 3 columns. Do you use the built-in browser on the TV? If you see only one column, i.e. the browser does not support grid :)

Comment: Yeah,the build browser on LG TV, how is the footer, he is with grid too, here is in 1 column too:)

Comment: @HristoNajdenov, as already mentioned it seems like the problem isn't your code, but the Browser, try to recreate the Layout with i.e. Flexbox and look if it works fine, then you know it exactly.

Comment: @HristoNajdenov you can use media query please refer this - [https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_mediaqueries.asp]